# soft keyboard lifts tabs upwords even if we close the keyboard in Android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-tabhost, android-softkeyboard, fragment-tab-host

I am stuck with this problem, after hiding soft keyboard the TABS still upwards.

I am using SCROLL_VIEW in my XML, but when I delete scroll keyboard works fine.

i have also used  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest.

[image: after click on edittext]

[image: after hiding keyboard, tabhost still upwards]

Comment: did you try adjustResize ?